# Help in simplifying this nasty expression obtained after binomial expnasion

Tags: exponential-function, closed-form, binomial-theorem, exponential-sum

I have arrived to the following expression and was wondering if anyone can help me further simplify to something nicer,

$$F= 1- [1-\text{exp} (- \alpha(N) ) ]^N= 1- \sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{N}{k} \bigg(- \text{exp} (- \alpha(N) )\bigg)^k$$

where $$ \alpha(N)= (N!)^{-{1}/{N}}$$

Any ideas?

Comment: General unpleasantness on this page is at an unusual level, even for math.SE.

Comment: you deleted your answers because someone downvoted whatever you said

Comment: Please do not ascribe to others your own mediocrity. I deleted my answer (singular) because you made it so that the "general unpleasantness on this page is at an unusual level, even for math.SE".

Answer (score 1):

i have got $2-\left(1-e^{(N!)^{-1/N}}\right)^N$ after an ugly calculation.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please give it another look